# Jquery Ajax with header "HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name" With ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have simple ajax call with two json object as below

```
var newModel = {
            CountryCode: $("#CountryCode").val(),
            LanguageCode: $("#LanguageCode").val(),

            PhoneId1: "1",
            PhoneNumber1: $phone1.val(), 
            Extension1: $ext1.val(), 

            PhoneId2: "2",
            PhoneNumber2: $phone2.val(), 
            Extension2: $ext2.val(),

            PhoneId3: "3",
            PhoneNumber3: $phone3.val(), 
            Extension3: $ext3.val(), 

            FirstName: $firstName.val(),
            LastName: $lastName.val() 
        };

        var currentModel = {
            CountryCode: oldModel.CountryCode,
            LanguageCode: oldModel.LanguageCode,

            PhoneId1: "1",
            PhoneNumber1: oldModel.UserPhoneDetail[0].PhoneNumber,
            Extension1: oldModel.UserPhoneDetail[0].Extension,

            PhoneId2: "2",
            PhoneNumber2: oldModel.UserPhoneDetail[1].PhoneNumber,
            Extension2: oldModel.UserPhoneDetail[1].Extension,

            PhoneId3: "3",
            PhoneNumber3: oldModel.UserPhoneDetail[2].PhoneNumber,
            Extension3: oldModel.UserPhoneDetail[2].Extension
        };

        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: apiUrl,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token },
                    data: JSON.stringify({ NewModel: newModel, OldModel: currentModel }),
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.isSuccess == "False")
                            phoneRegistration.ShowSecondaryAuthentication();
                        else {
                            $("#hdnShowSecondaryAuthentication").val("False");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                        debugger
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPosts]
    [IsUserAuthorize]
    public JsonResult ManageUserPhoneDetail(Jha.Pps.Portal.Ui.Core.Models.PhoneRegistrationViewModel model)
    {
        JsonResult jsResult = null;
        bool savePhoneRegistrationResult = false;
        savePhoneRegistrationResult = _secondaryAuthenticationController.SavePhoneRegistration(Request.ApplicationPath, CreateSecondaryAuthenticationModel(model.NewModel), CreateSecondaryAuthenticationModel(model.OldModel));
        if (savePhoneRegistrationResult) CurrentUserContext.IsPhoneRegistrationRequired = false;
        var data = new { isSuccess = savePhoneRegistrationResult };
        jsResult = Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return jsResult;
    }
```

Getting error : Bad Request - Invalid Header, 
HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name

error appear only when user logged in first time and I am not able to produce same error on local environment 
any suggestion

Comment: The issue is with the `__RequestVerificationToken`. Where are you getting the `token` value from?

Comment: your parameter is also mismaching with the method parameter ...that will also cause problem

Comment: var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
            var headers = {};
            headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token;

Comment: public class PhoneRegistrationViewModel
    {
        public SecondaryAuthenticationViewModel NewModel { get; set; }
        public SecondaryAuthenticationViewModel OldModel { get; set; }

    }